# How to use window.scroll to automatically scroll on pageload?

Tags: javascript

```
function Scrolldown() {
        window.scroll(0,300); 
    }
```

How can I use this function (or a similar one) to automatically scroll down when the page loads? (without clicking a link)

Regards,

taylor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
function Scrolldown() {
     window.scroll(0,300); 
}

window.onload = Scrolldown;
```

Comment: There shouldn't be parentheses with `Scrolldown`. That *calls* the function and assigns its *return value* to `window.onload`, whereas without the parentheses, it assigns the *function* to `window.onload`, which is what you should be after.

Answer (score 8):

you could include all of your javascript in an event. This will scroll to an element with an id.

```
<body onload="window.location='#myID';">
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = Scrolldown;
```

I also want to point out that you could use an HTML anchor to indicate where to scroll to, so you don't have to hard-code the pixel value:

```
<div id="iWantToScrollHere" name="iWantToScrollHere">
    ...
</div>
```

...which would make your `Scrolldown` function:

```
function Scrolldown() {
    window.location.hash = '#iWantToScrollHere';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could include jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then wrap your scrolling thing in a document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

window.scroll(0,300);

});
```

then after that you don't need to do anything.

:)

Answer (score 0):

well, another super simple script is here,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(e){ 
    window.scrollBy(1,1);
}
```

it worked best for me.