# Executing HTML/JavaScript On Page Load? (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript

On my wordpress site, I have created an button that, upon clicking it, will send you to a specific scroll position on the website. This is working great. My issue is getting this code to run once the web page has finished loading. Specifically to scroll to a position on the page that will hide the page header unless the user scrolls back to the top.

This is the JavaScript I've been attempting to use:

```
    <body onLoad="pageScroll(240)">
```

For reference, this is the HTML of the button I've created:

```
    <button onclick="document.documentElement.scrollTop = 240;document.body.scrollTop =240;">
    Click to scroll to beginning of content
    </button>
    </div>
```

Here is the entire contents of the header.php file:

http://pastebin.com/YxknizFU

I used pastebin because I couldn't figuire how to format the code properly

Comment: Can you post your script? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @TomásCot jQuery is installed in my wordpress site, if that's what you're asking. Please forgive me, I'm really new to all this.

Comment: Can you add the `pageScroll` function's code?

Comment: @TomásCot What I've put in the main post is actually all I've got. Unfortunately, I'm clearly missing something big. I think I would be able to get the script I currently have to work if I knew how to make it run when the page loads.

Comment: @TomásCot As I'm doing this in a wordpress enviornment, would I place this code in a certain file? If so, what do I surround the code with to tell wordpress to run the script? I've previously tried putting this code in the footer template, but this hasn't changed anything.

Comment: unless you have a function `pageScroll` defined, all your code will do is throw errors. Look in browser console to see if errors thrown

Comment: Saying you are new doesn't help, because the answer will never be "this code only works for experienced programmers: xyz".  Its just fluff and questions should be kept to just the actual question itself, no fluff.

Comment: the code in the header.php doesn't have the `onload` attribute added to the body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly then, all you need is to put your javascript scroll function on onload event,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function scrollToPosition()
{
  //put scroll logic here which you have set for button click event
 //alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="scrollToPosition()">
<h1>Example</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

or look into this thread

[body onLoad on a specific WordPress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148559/body-onload-on-a-specific-wordpress-page)

Comment: I gave this a go, and placed it at the end of my footer.php file. No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Please look into this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148559/body-onload-on-a-specific-wordpress-page

Answer (score 0):

To use your code, then try with this:

```
<body onload="document.body.scrollTop = 240">
```

You have to add the onload like this:

```
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> onload="pageScroll(0, 240)">
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
```

Comment: well, that's as simple as it gets. Did you add it to the theme? It should go in the `body`tag in the `header.php` file

Comment: I have placed this under what is definitely the 'body' tag, and it's in my header.php file. This is what I see as a 'body' tag:

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
 <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
 <div id="site-header">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
   <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?

I have inserted:
<body onload="pageScroll(0, 240)">

Comment: Apolagies for lack of word wrapping

Comment: Add the code to your question, and add the generated HTML, too.

Comment: Both have been added.

Comment: Well, it's not showing in what you posted in pastebin